# If I am buying a stock why don't just I buy an in the money option?

Tags: stocks, options, online-trading, robinhood

I'm  a 15 year stock market investor here who is very new to option trading (two weeks).   I have a full understanding of how options work (complicated needless to say) and I have  realized  their potential.

I have read  that is not a good idea to hold the options until expiration or to exercise them  but it does  make sense to me to hold them if I have enough money to buy them. I am using Robinhood so there are no commissions or fees.

Let's say that I plan to buy VUG in a couple of weeks when I get paid.  I can buy a two week call now and if it is above the break even price in a week and half, why don't I just leave it as is and wait to purchase the shares? I already buy shares every other week and I already made a profit for buying the option earlier.

Every single comment I have read on the internet states that I should not exercise. To me, since I am a buy and hold investor, it makes sense to purchase stock that way. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your motive, you want to buy an ITM call and intend to exercise regardless of price at expiration? The reason you want to do this is so that you can benefit from any upward movement over the next two weeks instead of missing out on that growth waiting to buy shares in 2 weeks?

Comment: Wouldn't a future be more appropriate if you intend to buy no matter what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that it is recommended  not to hold long options until expiration is that option premium decay is non linear.  It speeds up every day, faster and faster as expiration approaches.

The reason that it is not recommended  to exercise ITM options is that if there is time premium remaining, you throw it away by exercising.   So unless the time premium is pennies, it's usually a better idea to sell the option and execute the trade in the underlying.  The exception to this is when you own a deep ITM option and the bid is less than intrinsic value, but that's another story.

Your approach is a special situation.  You want to buy the underlying at later date but you want to lock in the price now by using a long call.  That's a valid approach.  The question is, should you be buying a two week call?

Since you didn't indicate the strike price and premium for the call that interests you, I'll just pick my own.  Strike prices near the money have the greatest amount of time premium and ITM options have less.  So for example, here are some July calls (VUG does not trade offer weekly options):

VUG $201.00

$175c 28.50 203.50  2.50

$180c 24.00 204.00 3.00

$185c19.70 204.70  3.70

$190c 14.90 204.90  3.90

$200c  7.40 207.40 6.40

The numbers above represent the strike price, the ask price of the call, the net cost of the stock and the time premium. As you can see, the lower the strike, the lower the time premium.  You pay dearly for buying the less costly ATM strike.

VUG options are not actively traded and they have low Open Interest. Therefore, they have very wide bid/ask spreads.  With some patience, you should be able to buy these for less.  Start at the midpoint (the average of the bid and ask) and work your way up if you want the position and you are willing to pay more.

An alternative approach if you have the appropriate option level approval, a margin account  and enough marginable securities to back the position would be to sell a short put.  With this strategy, you would receive the premium and time decay would be in your favor.  There's no guarantee that you would get the shares at a locked in price (buying the call) and then you would just earn income (the premium).

This may make your head hurt but if you combine both of the above, you would have a synthetic long position (sell the ATM put and use the proceeds to buy the ATM  call).  Let's say that it costs a dollar to do so.  If VUG rises, you exercise your long call for $200 and your net cost is $201.  If it drops and you are assigned on your short put, you pay $200 and your net cost is $201.  That's a significant savings versus buying a long call.

Comment: That answer is more than what I waiting for. so obviously I have way much more to learn. I will digest your reply slowly as there is a lot of information I am not familiar with. Any recommended books or internet sites where I can learn these type of strategies? I am just realizing how I could have been doing much much better had I started trading options 15 years ago instead of buying stocks outright (I did pretty well nevertheless). The media has been keeping me away from options because they characterize them as gambling instead of investing but now I realize how it is the opposite.

Comment: Sorry to overwhelm you but better more than less (g). The media is correct in regard to uninformed **trading** of options, aka gambling. However, there are conservative ways to utilize options, some less risky than outright ownership of the underlying. An example is buying high delta, low IV deep ITM LEAPs instead of the underlying.  Almost the same potential profit and less risk.  You can find a lot of good information on the internet but it tends to be superficial and sometimes, it's flat out incorrect. If you're learning, it's hard to discern the good from the bad.

Comment: AFAIC, the go to book for options is "Options as a Strategic Investment" by McMillan. 100 pages will give you a sound understanding of covered calls, synthetical equiv short puts and spreads. Should more complex strategies intrigue you, you can read more. You can get a used older edition for peanuts - no need to spend $75+ for the latest edition (1,000+ pages) since it involves more complex strategies which will likely not be of interest to you for years. After reading this book you'll be able to judge for yourself what other option books have to offer you (Hull, Taleb, Natenberg, etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I appreciate complicated answers; they give me things to think about. I just ordered the book you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If stocks have worked for you in the past, and if you don't have a very large amount of capital relative to the notional value of the options that you will trade, I think you should stick to stocks. The main issue with options is that each option contract is on 100 shares. If you would not buy or sell *at once* 100 shares of a stock, you should think several times before trading options on that stock because every time you are trading an option you are making a commitment to buy or sell 100 shares of the stock *at one price*. Another issue is liquidity. If liquidity is poor, you should stay away from that option unless you plan to hold it to maturity.

It is very hard to make profits *consistently* on options. Making money once or twice does not count. As for your example, if the stock price is above the strike price at option expiry you do get to buy the stock at a discount but note that you need to deduct the premium you paid for it from the discount. The discount has to be reasonably larger than the premium for you to make a decent profit. Also, you have to be able to cough up money for 100 shares at once. Much better would be to dollar cost average by buying fewer than 100 shares at any given time. Also, the time value of options tends to decay. That does not happen with stocks.

There is a good chance that you will lose your hard earned capital gains over the next few months if you are not discreet with the use of options. In my view, if you don't have large amounts of cash, it is best to stay away from them.

Comment: Your comments are appropriate for option traders but the OP's interest in options is for a specific circumstance.  He's looking to lock in a price now via options for a later date when he has the cash to acquire the shares,  He's not considering the trading of options.

Comment: The first paragraph is alarming. It is indicative of a rosy mindset with respect to options and that heralds danger. Next he asks why he should not hold a long call. I explain the cons in my answer through the "commitment to buy 100 shares" idea and how the discount is partly neutralized by the premium. And this is assuming that the option is in-the-money. Important is whether he can buy 100 shares *at once*. He just wrote he buys shares, but did not state how many at once. He is clearly excited about the "potential" of options and needs to be made aware of their potential for ruin too.

Comment: I agree buying will not hurt him much but he can still keep losing the premium either owing to time decay, or owing to expiry. More important is whether he has the willingness to buy 100 shares at one price if the option is in-the-money at expiry, and how much it is in-the-money.

Comment: Exchange traded options are for 100 shares so it's a given that if the OP doesn't have the money to support the exercise in two weeks, he's not getting the position.  Also, he indicated in his opening sentence that he understands how options work so all of this discussion about 100 shares and 'discount neutralized by premium' is overkill. And as I mentioned in my answer, he can achieve the position in the underlying and avoid most/all of the time premium costs that trouble you by simply doing a synthetic long.

Comment: Sometimes brokers assign the shares on margin. OP just says he "understands" options but also says he is new to options trading, and used words like "potential". So I thought a word of warning would not hurt. Your synthetic strategy does make sense from the point of view of it being free. But if the put goes in-the-money at expiry and if 100 shares cannot be bought there will be a loss. OP might as well dollar cost average because he does not pay commissions. The key is to determine whether one has the wherewithal to take delivery. If there is any doubt regarding that, one should go slow.

Comment: The following comment alarmed me in particular " I am just realizing how I could have been doing much much better had I started trading options 15 years ago instead of buying stocks outright (I did pretty well nevertheless)". and that it received an upvote.

Comment: The mistake here is that you're projecting all of the risk issues of option trading onto the OP who didn't express any desire to trade options, as in buying and selling them repeatedly.  He indicated that he wants to utilize options for the specific purpose of locking in the share purchase now with the funds being available in two weeks.

Comment: **But if the put goes in-the-money at expiry and if 100 shares cannot be bought there will be a loss**.  Shares will be purchased via assignment or via exercise regardless of share price at expiration other than the  infrequent pin risk expiration. In that case, the no cost synthetic expires and he then has the cash to buy the shares (more than 2 weeks from now).  The warning of possible loss on the short put isn't needed.  Buying 100 shares now offers the same potential loss. It's not a discussion of the risks of options but rather one of utilizing them in his specific circumstances. FINIS

Comment: I drew my inferences about what he thought of options from his comments. He regrets not having used options earlier. Also, as regards "Buying 100 shares now offers the same potential loss." it is not clear that he wants to buy 100 shares at once. If he is ready to do that, then he could use the no cost synthetic. But there is always pin risk as you point out. He could also dollar cost average, and avoid the pin risk altogether. But it really depends on how much cash he has. If he can buy 100 shares at the put strike, he is good.

Comment: Thanks to all for your replies. I am planning to buy 100 shares of ETFs. I successfully executed the strategy I am asking about. I paid for a one week call for ESPO. I would have needed to pay about $5,000; instead I bought one call in the money, I paid $100 and at the end of the week it ended at $52. I made an extra $100 and now I own 100 shares. I then sold a call for $53 and made an extra $100. since I will hold those 100 share for.. as Buffet would say... ever!  looks to me it is a low risk way to make more money. I mean, I will hold and want to own those shares.

Comment: @Igalico " I paid $100 and at the end of the week it ended at $52. I made an extra $100 and now I own 100 shares. " How did you make $100 here? "I then sold a call for $53 and made an extra $100." What $100 are you referring to here?

Comment: When I sold the call I got about $100 and since the stock was at $52.46 at the end of the week I did not have to sell my shares so I kept the premium

Comment: BoB Bearker --- This may make your head hurt but if you combine both of the above, you would have a synthetic long position (sell the ATM put and use the proceeds to buy the ATM call). Let's say that it costs a dollar to do so. If VUG rises, you exercise your long call for $200 and your net cost is $201. If it drops and you are assigned on your short put, you pay $200 and your net cost is $201. That's a significant savings versus buying a long call. ---  Now I understand! This is actually genius!

Comment: I understand the synthetic long. But I don't understand how you made "an extra $100" if you paid $100 for the call and at the end of the week it ended at $52. Did you sell an out-of-the-money call simultaneously?

Comment: I wanted to buy 100 shares of ESPO, it was at $50 per share so I would have paid $5,000. I decided to buy a call for one week for $100 instead. At the end of the week the stock was at $52 and I let the call execute so I purchased shares worth $5,200 but only paid $5,000 for the shares plus $100 for the call. I got $100 more than if I would have bought the shares at the beggining of the week.

Comment: OK. If the stock price had fallen you would have lost the $100. Also, if the $53 strike call comes in-the-money you will lose your shares. What you are doing is different from what Bob Baerker suggested. He did not suggest to short a call. But I might be mistaken. I will let him reply.